# Correct way of asking a waiter to bring one more

Tags: sentence-construction

Lets say I've had a small piece of butter and a small pot of jam coming with my breakfast. Now I'd like to ask one more. What would be the correct way to ask?

> Can I have one more for each of them?
>
> Can I have each of them one more?

Or how would a native ask for it?
Thanks

Comment: In the USA, we'd just ask for "extra butter and jam."

Comment: The close vote here for being "opinion-based" is entirely frivolous. Perhaps it's reasonable to close as a duplicate, if you can find one, but this seems to be exactly the kind of question where a native speaker is most useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to ask, for example:

> Could I please get another X?
>
> May I please have one more X?
>
> Would you please bring me some more X?

The "please" (if you choose to use it) can go various places in the sentence:

> *(Please)* would you *(please)* get me another X *(, please)*?

There are many variations of could/can/may/might/would, and get/have/bring, as well as other expressions.

> I'd like some more butter and jam, please.
>
> Please may I have some more butter and jam?

You can also add "excuse me" before, and/or "thank you" after, for extra politeness:

> Excuse me, but might I ask you for more butter and jam?  Thanks.
>
> Excuse me, but could I trouble you for some more butter and jam?  Thank you.

If you're unhappy with the service, and you don't feel like being as polite, you could instead use the imperative:

> Bring me some more butter and jam, please.
>
> Get me another plate of butter and more jam?  Thanks.

This is not a comprehensive list.  There are many variations on all of the above examples.

Comment: That's great answer. Thanks. So what if I need to use "each" in the sentence? Can I say something like "Could I please get another each of them?" or "Could I please one more for each of them?"

Comment: "Could I please get one more of each?"